# SMOTE throws a cython error during fit_resample

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, imbalanced-data, smote, oversampling

I have a data frame that looks like below

[image]

where column 'ETR' is my label having classes 0 to 4. Since the classes are imbalanced (with 0 being the majority class), I used SMOTE to oversample the data frame.

from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

```
oversample = SMOTE()
X, y = oversample.fit_resample(X, y)
```

However, I get the below error when doing so

> TypeError: C function sklearn.utils._cython_blas.__pyx_fuse_0_dot has
> wrong signature (expected float (int, float const *, int, float const
> *, int), got float (int, float *, int, float *, int))

I tried converting all my columns to int but I still get the same error. May I know what might have caused this?